MDI Child border drawing problem in Delphi 12.1
MDI Child is without caption. In CreateParams, i set Params.Style := (Params.Style) and (not ws_Caption) ;
Not using VCL Styles.
1a. In the top border, the form caption is visible. The height of top border is much smaller than the text height, but part of the text can be seen.
1b. I have set BorderIcons to []. But if BI is set to [systemmenu,maximize] then at the extreme left and extreme right of top border, you can see some colored pixels. Clicking on them opens the system menu or maximizes the form. The border though thin is acting as caption.

On zooming form and then unzooming, the left and bottom borders don't get redrawn. The pixels of the zoomed form is still present uncleared.
To zoom/unzoom, i handle double click event of form and set the windowstate to wsnormal or wsmaximized.

Delphi 12.1 MDI improvements!!!

Does this answer your question? MDI Child with no caption - Delphi 12.1 behaviour has changed
